# OpenMP flush and consistency of all threads

Tags: multithreading, locking, openmp, memory-fences

When some thread performs `omp_set_lock`, an implicit flush is performed.

But does that mean that after the flush by this particular thread, all other threads will update their private view to value from shared memory even though they don't perform flush themselves. Or will they still read values from private view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: in order to have a consistent view, all threads must perform a flush.  This is explained in Section 1.4.3 of the spec.

Comment: So does that mean a thread writes back to memory only at a flush operation. Till that it never writes back?

Comment: @user3639559, in the absence of flush operations, you have no guarantees — the OpenMP implementation can choose to write to memory straight away, or it can delay writing until the next flush.  Please read Section 1.4 of the spec, it is fairly well written.